# postgres: I can't see queries logged queries. Log files are empty

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to master database queries optimization. And as a first step I need to log all queries (and their execution time to log files). My config file looks this way (I believe I have turned on the most important things): https://gist.github.com/oltarasenko/5f839214828e4cb95d47

And log files seem to be created after server restart (and have normal looking rw permissions). But they are just empty.

```
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres    0 Jul 19 14:46 postgresql-2014-07-19_144638.log
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres    0 Jul 19 14:51 postgresql-2014-07-19_145107.log
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres    0 Jul 19 14:58 postgresql-2014-07-19_145622.log
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres    0 Jul 19 14:58 postgresql-2014-07-19_145859.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that logging goes into `syslog` only because of your directive :

`log_destination = 'syslog'`

You shoud try either :

```
log_destination = 'stderr'
```

This will generate (non empty) `*.log` files

or

```
log_destination = 'csvlog'
```

This will generate (non empty) `*.csv` files

I would recommend `csvlog` because it will be easier to parse later for result analysis.

However you can use a combination of all (coma separated) :

```
log_destination = 'stderr,csvlog,syslog'
```